# Smart Capture Form - primary key identifier

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page, smart-capture

we have a workshop at which we'd like to ask the participants to evaluate the quality of the workshop using the SmartCapture form on a cloud page. We have already created the form-related data extension which includes the participants' EmailAddress, FirstName, LastName, Country, and ContactID, which we assigned to them. It also has the field to be used in the survey (i.e. "Feedback"). The data extension's primary key is the combination of EmailAddress and ContactID. Now, we would like to have only the "How did you like the workshop" question (field: Feedback) on the form, without asking them to provide their EmailAddress and/or ContactID. What happens is that during testing, the form cannot be submitted/validate without those fields being included, so nothing happens after filling out the form.

Comment: You'll need to provide a little more information. How are you populating the required fields? And how would you know who is the person filling out the form if you're only asking them "How did you like the workshop?"

Comment: Hi, JacksonChen, the attendees data is already present in the target data extension (name, surname, email address, etc.). We only want to ask them how they liked the workshop, and tie the answer to the attendee entry in the data extension (sort of a hidden identifier).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll give this a stab. Pass the `EmailAddress`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Country`, and `ContactID` data attributes to the page where your Smart Capture is hosted. If it's in a CloudPage use `CloudPageURL`.

Then on the actual form use hidden input values and populate those hidden input values with the data passed from the email.
If using CloudPages, use `RequestParameter` to assign your data attributes to AMPscript variables:

```
<input type = "hidden" value="%%=v(@EmailAddress)=%%>
```

Your form will be validated and should submit because you are submitting those data values as hidden inputs.

Comment: Ok, I was suggested this approach in the past. I'll try it again.

Comment: Sounds good. Please select this as the answer if it solves your question